# Content from variable and object of my Node Instance isn't getting printed out

Tags: java, dictionary, tree, instance, println

### Note

**The program works just fine, the thing is when trying to print the dictionary tree out, it doesn't print the word itself:**
+++++Spanisch Woerterbuch+++++++
Bitte waehlen Sie eine Aktion aus!

1. Einfuegen     2. Suchen       3. Beenden
   1
   Bitte geben Sie ein Wort ein:
   Viaje
   Bitte geben Sie die Bedeutung ein:
   Reise
   Wort:  **<------The mistake/ error arises here**
   Bedeutung: Reise
   Bitte waehlen Sie eine Aktion aus!
   *1. Einfuegen     2. Suchen       3. Beenden*

## Node class

```
public class Node{
    private String word, definition;
    private Node left, right;
    
    
    public Node (String w, String def){
        this.word = w;
        this.definition = def;
    }
    
    public String getW(){   return this.word;   }
    
    public String getD(){   return this.definition; }
    
    public Node getL(){ return this.left;   }
    
    public Node getR(){ return this.right;  }
    
    public void setL(Node l){   this.left = l;  }
    
    public void setR(Node r){    this.right = r;    }
}
```

## Tree class

```
public class Tree{
    
    Node root;
    
    // sorting insert
    public void insert(Node newWord){
        
        if ( root == null)  root = newWord;
        
        else insert(root, newWord);
    }
    
    protected void insert(Node temp, Node newWord){ // Hello, Tree
        if (newWord.getW().compareTo(temp.getW()) < 0){
            if (temp.getL() == null )   temp.setL(newWord);
            
            else insert(temp.getR(), newWord);
        
        } else{
                if (temp.getR() == null)    temp.setR(newWord);
                
                else insert(temp.getR(), newWord); // "end", "Tree"
        }
    }
    
    // Output of the entire tree/ dictionary
    public void print(){
        print(root);
    }
    
    protected void print(Node temp){
        if (temp.getL() != null )   print(temp.getL());
        
        System.out.println("Wort: " + temp.getW());
        System.out.println("Bedeutung: " + temp.getD());
        
        if (temp.getR() != null )   print(temp.getR());
    }
    
    public void search(String word){
        
        search(root, word);
        /**
            @return this.definition or null 
        */  
    }
    
    protected String search(Node root, String toBeFound){
        if ( root == null)  return null;
        
        if ( root.getW().compareTo(toBeFound) == 0){
            System.out.println("Bedeutung vom gesuchten Wort: " + root.getD());
            return root.getD();
        }
        
        if (root.getW().compareTo(toBeFound) > 0){
            return search(root.getL(), toBeFound);
        }
        
        return search(root.getR(), toBeFound);
    }
    
    // optional
    public void delete(Node word){
    
    }
}
```

## Dictionary class

```
import java.util.*;

public class Dict{
    static Tree t = new Tree();
    static int menu;
    static String word, definition;
    static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    static boolean programRunning = true;
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("+++++Spanisch Woerterbuch+++++++");
        while ( programRunning ){
            showMenu();
        }
        
        
        
        s.close();
    }
    
    private static void showMenu(){

        System.out.println("Bitte waehlen Sie eine Aktion aus!");
        System.out.printf("1. Einfuegen\t 2. Suchen\t 3. Beenden");
        System.out.println();
        menu = s.nextInt();
    
        switch (menu){
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie ein Wort ein:");
            word = s.nextLine();
            s.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie die Bedeutung ein:");
            definition = s.nextLine();
            Node node = new Node(word, definition);
            t.insert(node);
            t.print();
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie das zu suchende Wort ein:");
            s.nextLine();
            word = s.nextLine();
            t.search(word);
            break;
        case 3:
            programRunning = false;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Ungueltige Eingabe!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fairly straightforward issue.

```
Scanner#nextInt()
```

does not read the newline symbol, and you wrote

```
word = s.nextLine();
s.nextLine();
```

which means the first `nextLine()` will consume the `\n` and output an **empty string**, while the second will actually read your inputted text, but simply discard it.
Thus, swap them

```
s.nextLine();
word = s.nextLine();
```

and you're done. Keep also in mind debuggers exist, try to use them if possible.

Comment: Thanks man, I was aware of that, but put the scanner.nxtLine() on the wrong position to consume the /n

Comment: @TorbenIT this happens to everyone, don't worry.